# What is causing these TypeScript Element errors with this array of React components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

Can anyone please advise on what is causing and how to fix the following TypeScript errors I am getting with an array of returned Button components. Here is the relevant Button component code:-

```
type type = 'primary' | 'secondary' | 'tertiary' | 'tertiary_variant';
type size = 'base' | 'small' | 'micro';

type Props = typeof Button.defaultProps & {
    type: type;
    size: size;
    className: string;
    disabled: boolean;
    busy: boolean;
    onClick: (event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement>) => void;
    children: any;
    attributes: any;
    submitButton: boolean;
};

type ButtonRipple = {
    top: number;
    left: number;
    id: string;
}

type State = {
  ripples: ButtonRipple[];
}

class Button extends Component<Props, State> {
    static defaultProps = {
        type: 'primary',
        size: 'base',
        className: null,
        disabled: false,
        busy: false,
        attributes: {},
        submitButton: false
    };
    private readonly buttonRef: React.RefObject<unknown>;
    constructor(props: Props) {
        super(props);
        this.buttonRef = React.createRef();

        this.state = {
            ripples: []
        };
    }....
```

Here is the function from the parent component that returns the Buttons:-

```
generateButtons = (): Button[] => {     
        return [
254         <Button
                key="cancel"
                type="tertiary"
                onClick={this.props.onClose}
                attributes={{                
                    'aria-label': 'Cancel'
                }}
            >
                Cancel
            </Button>,
265         <Button
                key="submit"
                onClick={this.handleSubmit}
                attributes={{                   
                    'aria-label': 'Submit'
                }}
                className={styles.submitButton}
            >
                Submit
            </Button>           
        ];
    };
```

And here are the errors:-

```
Error:(254, 13) TS2740: Type 'Element' is missing the following properties from type 'Button': buttonRef, handleClick, createRipple, render, and 5 more.
Error:(265, 13) TS2322: Type 'Element' is not assignable to type 'Button'.
```

Thanks,

Sam

Comment: We can't see which lines the errors apply to. Please update your question to make that more explicit

Comment: The defaultValue for className is `null` but it's type is string. Consider not giving className a value and allowing it to be `undefined`. So in type for Props: `{ className?: string }` which will allow className to be `string | undefined`.

Comment: @AndyRay I have updated the line numbers now which are relevant.

Comment: @KevinBai Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The root cause of your problem is that `<Button .../>` is not an instance of `Button`, instead it's a `JSX.Element`. If you need a reference to a Button to access its methods, you can use the [`ref`](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html) mechanism in `React`.

To explain why the errors are so cryptic, typescript allows assigning objects of one class to references of another, as long as their interfaces match. In your case `JSX.Element` doesn't implement all requirements for the `Button` interface.